# Show Product on Search Page - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, tags

Currently I have a snippet of code that will forward a user to the product page if they search for a term and only 1 product is associated with that keyword.

```
<?php if($this->getResultCount() == 1): ?> 
<?php $prodId = $this->_productCollection->getAllIds() ?> 
<?php $singleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId) ?> 
<?php header('Location: ' . $singleProduct->getProductUrl()) ?> 
<?php exit; ?> 
<?php elseif($this->getResultCount()): ?>
```

However, what I want to do now is actually serve up the product and all its details on the results page itself if its the only one with that tag/search term INSTEAD of redirecting to the product page. Im pretty new to php so please bear with me.

Comment: It's possible but why would you do that exactly ? Secondly, do not use header function in a template.. that's ugly. You need to learn about PHP, MVC and just magento framework before trying to code anything else ... believe me

Answer (score 0):

Block template is bad place for this. Good place - controller.
Maybe you need rewrite controller for this functionality. 
For example/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php

In controller your code looks like:

`$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($_product->getProductUrl());`